Orthogonal projector from oblique projector
I stumbled upon this formula (without citation) for constructing the orthogonal projector from an oblique projector, but I can't seem to find a source for it.
Let $H,V$ be complementary subspaces of $T$. Let $P: T \to H$ be the oblique projector along $V$ onto $H$. Then the orthogonal projector $P^\perp$ onto $H$ is given by
$$P^\perp = P(P^TP)^{-1}P^T$$
Is this correct ? And if so where can I cite this ?
Alternatively, I think one should be able to proof it using Eq. (5.13.3) from "Matrix Analysis & Linear Algebra"(Meyer 2000) which says that if the columns of $M_{n\times r}$ form a basis of $H$, then the orthogonal projector is given by
$$P^\perp = M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T$$
with $r = dim(H)$ and $n = dim(T)$.
An idea for a proof was to consider the full-rank decomposition $P = M F$ and equivalently transform the equations into each other using pseudo-inversion, but I wasn't able to do it.
Thanks for your help.

Your desired fact is just a special case of the result from the textbook you are citing.

Thanks @ChristianRemling :) that solves it for me.
